# Field names overlapping react material UI

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I have a simple react component created using material UI

```
function TableField(id) {
    return (
        <div className='flex' id={id}>
            <TextField class="mr-2" id='0' label="Field type" variant="outlined" value='2' />
            <TextField class="mr-2" id='1' label="Field Name" variant="outlined" value='3' />
        </div>
    );
}
```

ISSUE:
In the website the fields label are overlapping each other.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

What I have tried:
As mentioned in [Another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955603/react-material-ui-label-overlaps-with-text) I tried adding values to my text fields as well but it did not work out.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you styling the `div` element and also the parent element of this component? The problem has to be coming from them.

Comment: I'm using tailwind css and material UI nothing else for styling