# Chrome Autofill causes textbox collision for Textfield Label and Value

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui

In React, Autocomplete Chrome values don't trigger onChange event immediately. Thus it causes a collision of MUI TextField Label and actual values, during initial loading of page.
How can I resolve this issue ?

[image]

Trying numerous methods, InputLabelProps shrink on Value does not work either. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65070465/15435022

```
<StyledTextField
    fullWidth
    id="email"
    label="Email"
    size="medium"
    value={emailAddress}
    onChange={(e) => setEmailAddress(e.target.value)}
    error={emailError}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: emailAddress != null && emailAddress != "" ? true : false,
    }}
    helperText={emailError ? "Please enter a valid email" : "Required"}
 />
```

Trying this solution also gives issues:  when doing `const theme = createTheme({`

Github resource:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/14427#issuecomment-466054906

[image]

Comment: I think you can use `onInput` in `inputProps` instead of `onChange`. But I'm not sure it's working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Personally, I don't think the juice is worth the squeeze for this vs just disabling shrink or auto-complete for the log-in, but no one asked my opinion, so...*

From what I understand, the reason this is more painful than we'd like is because it was *originally* intended as a security feature to prevent password theft via auto-complete, but once Chrome (et al.) removed the restrictions, React's de-duping mechanism took over. There are some [slightly more hack-y work-arounds](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/36448#issuecomment-1556738360) than what I'm going to suggest, but you can decide which you like.

To side-step this, you can add a handler to each `input`'s `onAnimationStart` event, check if the `animationName` is `"mui-auto-fill"`, and then check if the `input` has a [`-webkit-autofill` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill), to see if the browser has auto-filled the field. You'll also want to handle the `"mui-auto-fill-cancel"` case for scenarios where the form is auto-filled and the user clears the values (to reset `shrink`.)

For example:

```
const [passwordHasValue, setPasswordHasValue] = React.useState(false);

// For re-usability, I made this a function that accepts a useState set function
// and returns a handler for each input to use, since you have at least two 
// TextFields to deal with.
const makeAnimationStartHandler = (stateSetter) => (e) => {
  const autofilled = !!e.target?.matches("*:-webkit-autofill");
  if (e.animationName === "mui-auto-fill") {
    stateSetter(autofilled);
  }

  if (e.animationName === "mui-auto-fill-cancel") {
    stateSetter(autofilled);
  }
};
...

<TextField
  type="password"
  id="password"
  inputProps={{
    onAnimationStart: makeAnimationStartHandler(setPasswordHasValue)
  }}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: passwordHasValue
  }}
  label="Password"
  value={password}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
    ...
  }}
/>
```

The result **on load** should appear as:

[image: example]

**Update** with cancel -- allows user to clear out the form field, after load with auto-fill, and the label is reset:

[image: example with reset field]

*FYI: I made my `makeAnimationStartHandler` a function that accepts a `React.useState()` setter as a param and returns a handler that actually does the work because your example has two fields and I wanted to 1) reduce code and 2) allow you to still handle the manual entry use-case for each field separately, if desired.*

**Working Example:** https://z3vxm7.csb.app/
**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/autofill-and-mui-label-shrink-z3vxm7?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: for some reason its not working, the label always Stays on Top, even when textbox is empty on mine

Comment: @mattsmith5 Ah I missed the cancel animation in my example -- I've updated my answer.

Comment: @SteveGomez Also there would be usefull to shrink it on focus as it is default behaviour. I am gonna fork it with focus and blur handler.

https://codesandbox.io/s/autofill-and-mui-label-shrink-forked-kd9699

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this Steve. Works great. I wrote a component for my project based on your answer:

```
import {TextField} from "@mui/material";
import {useCallback, useState} from "react";

const AutoFillAwareTextField = ({onChange, inputProps, InputLabelProps, ...rest}) => {

    const [fieldHasValue, setFieldHasValue] = useState(false)
    const makeAnimationStartHandler = (stateSetter) => (e) => {
        const autofilled = !!e.target?.matches("*:-webkit-autofill");
        if (e.animationName === "mui-auto-fill") {
            stateSetter(autofilled);
        }

        if (e.animationName === "mui-auto-fill-cancel") {
            stateSetter(autofilled);
        }
    }

    const _onChange = useCallback((e) => {
        onChange(e.target.value);
        setFieldHasValue(e.target.value !== "")
    }, [onChange])

    return <TextField
        inputProps={{
            onAnimationStart: makeAnimationStartHandler(setFieldHasValue),
            ...inputProps
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: fieldHasValue,
            ...InputLabelProps
        }}
        onChange={_onChange}
        {...rest}
    />
}
export default AutoFillAwareTextField
```