# Add useMemo or useCallback on textfield onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React 17 with MUI v4 and I have a problem on my textfield. When I type fast in my textfield input, the render is very slow. I seen this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819260/react-input-onchange-lag).

So I'd like to add a `useCallback` or `useMemo` on this onChange event but I don't know ho I can do it. I never used them.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      city: "",
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  ...

  render() {

    return (
          <TextField
            label="City"
            name="city"
            value={this.state.city}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
          />
         ...
```

How can I do to use `useCallback` or `useMemo` to get better performance ?

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would benefit from `useCallback` or `useMemo`. Since this is a class component, your `handleChange` function is essentially already memoized. What's in `TextField`? Could that be causing your poor performance?

Comment: @Cully Yep it's exactly my code. `TextField` is the MUI  component v4 https://v4.mui.com/components/text-fields/#text-field